# Is there a way to have iOS' autocorrect ignore a single word or regex in a UITextView?

Tags: ios, uitextview, autocorrect

I'm building a textview to compose status messages, and one of the functions it has is to include #hashtags within the text of a status message.

However, these #hashtags often aren't actual *words*, so iOS' autocorrect functionality causes them to appear with a red underline once the hashtag has been typed.

(For example: #seafair2014, #wwdc, and other non-word hashtags)

**Is there a way to temporarily add a term to the iOS dictionary, so as to ignore any #hashtag or @username typos but still provide spell-checking for the rest of the `UITextView`?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `+[UITextChecker learnWord:]`. You can listen to change events and dynamically add hashtag words.

[Apple Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextChecker_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITextChecker/ignoreWord:)